# How to make a modulo operation in objective-c / cocoa touch?

Tags: iphone, modulo

I have two CGFloat values, and want to calculate the modulo result. Or in other words: I want to know what's left if valueA is placed as much as possible into valueB.

So I just tried:

```
CGFloat moduloResult = valueB % valueA;
```

the compiler complains about the % and tells me: "invalid operands to binary %". Any idea?

Answer (score 207, accepted):

% is for `int` or `long`, not `float` or `double`.

You can use `fmod()` or `fmodf()` from `<math.h>` instead.

Better is [`<tgmath.h>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tgmath.h) as [suggested by the inventor of CGFloat](https://web.archive.org/web/20150806150437/http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/239717-cgfloat-fmax-fmaxf.html#239897).

Comment: is tgmath.h available on the iphone? I wonder because I never had to include math.h. It comes with the foundation framework, I think.

Comment: Also what's the difference between tgmath.h and math.h anyway?

Comment: Jim: `tgmath.h` is "type generic" (hence the "tg") and thus will decide which `math.h` function to call given the type of your input. (For instance, calling `floor(x)` with `tgmath.h` included will call (from `math.h`) `floorf(x)` if `x` is a `float`, `floor(x)` if `x` is a `double`, or `floorl(x)` if `x` is a `long double`.)

Answer (score 11):

If I remember correctly modulo requires 2 ints as its input so you'd need something like:

```
CGFloat moduloResult = (float)((int)valueB % (int)valueA);
```

Assuming that valueB and valueA are both floats

Comment: This, of course, will not give you the correct answer, because of rounding.

Comment: this seems like a ridiculous answer, but it's often pretty close to what you need. Of course you'll get rounding but when you're dealing with CGSizes etc., this is totally fine.