# XCode error "invalid operands to binary expression"

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

I have an NSTimeInterval that is stored as a double. I would like to get the amount of minutes that are inide of the second value using the % operator.

```
int remainingSeconds = scratch % 60;
```

The error said "invalid operands to binary expression" point at %
Help please.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

modulus is used on integers, so for your code to work do the following

```
int remainingSeconds = (int)scratch % 60;
```

To use modulus on floats use fmod

```
int remainingSeconds = fmod(scratch, 60);
```

check answer here [How to make a modulo operation in objective-c / cocoa touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271102/how-to-make-a-modulo-operation-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)