# modulo of doubles in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, double, modulo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make a modulo operation in objective-c / cocoa touch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271102/how-to-make-a-modulo-operation-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)

Can somebody explain to me why here the value of "myModValue" is 1.73472e-18
but when x would be 0.1 or 0.4 it's correctly 0?
Is there a better way to get the modulo-value of two doubles?

```
double x = 0.3;
double y = 0.1;
double myModValue = fmod(x, y);
```

Thanks Michael

EDIT:
Tried the above code hardcoded (so not with the values of my project-variables) and the result is 0.1
I don't know why...

Comment: @Monolo No there's only explained how to do modulo operations with double values. So fmod() is the right function I think, but I'm getting this unexplainable result ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floating point numbers are not precisely accurate due to rounding errors, the value 1.73472e-18 is essentially 0 in floating point terms. This is why you shouldn't compare floats with ==.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614533/strange-problem-comparing-floats-in-objective-c).

Comment: And harcoding the values means that the calculations are done by the compiler and rounded somehow - resulting in zero.