# Arc4random error: "Invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float')"

Tags: ios, uibutton, arc4random

I want to create a button at random position in certain view. I searched and read some SO topics however I couldn't find the solution for my problem.

Here is my code:

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CGRect buttonRect = button1.frame;
buttonRect.size = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
button1.frame = buttonRect;

[self.arr addObject:button1];

int r = ([button1 frame].size.width)/2;

int x = r + (arc4random() % (self.view.frame.size.width - button1.frame.size.width));
int y = r + (arc4random() % (self.view.frame.size.height - button1.frame.size.height));
//ERROR:Invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float')

[button1 setCenter:CGPointMake(x, y)];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a modulo operation in objective-c / cocoa touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271102/how-to-make-a-modulo-operation-in-objective-c-cocoa-touch)

Comment: `width` is `CGfloat` so you are getting error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mod (%) doesn't work on floats.

```
int x = r + (arc4random() % (int)(self.view.frame.size.width - button1.frame.size.width));
int y = r + (arc4random() % (int)(self.view.frame.size.height - button1.frame.size.height));
```

---

As an additional note, `arc4random() % …` is [not recommended](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/arc4random.3.html).

Here is the preferred method:

```
int x = r + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.width - button1.frame.size.width);
int y = r + arc4random_uniform(self.view.frame.size.height - button1.frame.size.height);
```

Answer (score 3):

try changing

```
int x = r + (arc4random() % (self.view.frame.size.width - button1.frame.size.width));
int y = r + (arc4random() % (self.view.frame.size.height - button1.frame.size.height));
```

to

```
int x = r + (arc4random() % ((int)(self.view.frame.size.width - button1.frame.size.width)));
int y = r + (arc4random() % ((int)(self.view.frame.size.height - button1.frame.size.height)));
```

It probably throws that error because you are trying to calculate modulus using a float as parameter

Comment: You would need to have the `(int)` cast outside of the parentheses, wouldn’t you?

Comment: @JefferyThomas and my explanation is slightly longer ;P